# Split String at specific character in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

We want to split a string by a specific characters without delete the char.
for example, if the input is: `if (x>4) then {x = 1}`
the output need to be: `if, (, x, >, 4, ), then, {, x, =, 1, }`

- we try to use `characterSetWithCharactersInString` but it remove the characters from the string..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't figured it out yet, the following will work:

```
NSString *input = @"if (x>4) then {x = 1}";
NSMutableArray *splitArray = [NSMutableArray array];    
NSCharacterSet *specialChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"(){}[]<>{}="];    
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];    
while (![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] intoString:&buffer])
    {
        [splitArray addObject:buffer];            
    }
    else if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:specialChars intoString:&buffer])
    {
        [splitArray addObject:buffer];            
    }
    else 
    {
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];
    }
}    
NSLog(@"%@", splitArray);
```

You can add whatever characters you want to specialChars.

PS: I read about NSScanner for the first time today and this worked as a good exercise to use it for real! I'd recommend you go through this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html

Comment: Thanks! I just now see your answer but it's still "WOW" :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Then do something like

```
 NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myString];
 BOOL foundIf = [scanner scanString:@"if" intoString:nil];
 // etc...
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not so good, because it's only return true when 'if' exsiting in the text.
but it's not split (into array for example) the text (in order).

Comment: Right. I was assuming (from your question) that you are trying to implement some kind of a script parser. If that's what you're trying to do, splitting at spaces isn't really a good idea. It's not going to be very flexible. What if I don't want to put spaces around my '=' signs (you actually did that with your > sign)?. Using a scanner or regular expressions would be much more flexible.